# Replicating IIS multiple worker processes in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, iis, process, worker

We have a website which is set up to work over multiple worker processes in IIS. On loading a certain page we're getting the classic "Object not set to an instance of an object" error. I want to try and replicate this in Visual Studio, is there a way to set Visual Studio up so that it's effectively running over multiple worker processes as in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

You can host websites on IIS if you have Windows Home Premium Plus or better.

Just install IIS, add your site, bind it to 'sitename.dev' and then wdit your c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file. Please use visual studio because it requires admin permissions.

Add line like this to hosts. file:

```
127.0.0.1 sitename.dev
```

check all is correct by ping sitename.dev - it should go to 127.0.0.1.

Then you are able to setup multimple processes, similar like on server, and debug it from VS.NET using Debug - Attach to process (look for w3p.exe  in processes list).